# is there a way to filter/search items to return a list from sqlite android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a function in SqliteDatabase.java, in which i want to **return an Arraylist of Items by filtering/searching** from SQLiteOpenHelper. i have followed so many examples but it seems complicated. any solution is helpful. Thank you

**SqliteDatabase.java**

```
public class SqliteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "question";
private static final String TABLE_QUESTIONS = "questions";

private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_COURSENAME = "coursename";
private static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "question";
private static final String COLUMN_ANSWER = "answer";
private static final String COLUMN_HINT = "hint";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION1 = "option1";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION2 = "option2";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION3 = "option3";
private static final String COLUMN_OPTION4 = "option4";


public SqliteDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_QUESTIONS +
                    "(" + COLUMN_ID +
                    " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_COURSENAME +
                    " TEXT," + COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ANSWER + " TEXT," + COLUMN_HINT + " TEXT," + COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_OPTION4 + " TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTIONS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public ArrayList<QuestionM> filter(String txt){
     ArrayList<QuestionM> filteredQuestions = new ArrayList<>(); 

     //here, i want to filter list of QuestionM by course

    return filteredQuestions;
}
```

**QuestionM.java**

```
public class QuestionM {
int id;
private String course ,question, answer,hint, option1, option2, option3 ,option4;

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy in java 8 APIs, such as streams. It has a filter to help you resolve the problem easily. you can also look up the Mybatis framework to resolve this problem within SQL-Query.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple and efficient if you using Kotlin, you simple use 'filters',

```
val filteredQuestions =  completeQuestions.filter { quesstion-> question.course == "your course you need to filter" }
```

With java you can use Streams API, earlier it was supported for minimun API version 24, good news is now you can utilise Java 8 language APIs without requiring a minimum API level for your app. - **https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring**

Streams example,

```
List<QuestionM> filteredQuestions = completeQuestions.stream()
                        .filter(s -> s.getCourse().equals("yourcourse"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```